# Any advantage of building class library as .NET Standard for this use case

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

Let's say I need to build a class library project that will be used by .NET Core web/desktop applications. In that case, is there any advantage of building that class library as a `.NET standard`, or is it better to build just as a `.NET Core` Class library project?

Comment: if you only care about .net core, create it as .net core if you want to use the lib in other .net implementations (Xamarin, .net framework) create .net standard 2.0 lib.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your .Net Standard class lib can be referenced from all .NET implementations, such as .NET Framework, .NET Core and Xamarin.

In practice, it's better you build separately for each targeted framework, there could be a lot of dlls in your .Net Standard lib package. Check details elaborated by https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET

Comment: The second paragraph only shows misunderstanding of that great article. Except certain .NET Framework versions might receive some love by compiling a specific version of your assembly to net4xx, there is no other platform requiring that. So saying “each” is incorrect.